Improving the LCP for Speed Optimization of my website
I have been diving into getting my page speed scores up to snuff, and I have run into a snag when it comes to how Google is measuring my LCP metric. No matter what I seem to do, this metric is always high and when it comes to using the tips and tricks that come along with Google's tutorial; nothing seems to be touching this.
I am currently using WordPress, and a theme called Media Center. Below is a link to the page speed analysis showing an LCP of 4370ms which I would love to get down to a more manageable number:
Page Speed Insights
I currently have everything I can preloading with a fetch priority of high above the fold, and there is critical css in place. I am also using WP Rocket & Imagify to both compress everything, and covert everything to a WEBP format. Everything preloading is omitted from being lazy-loaded so I don't have any discrepancies, and yet this metric just will not improve.
For context sake, I have another website where I rebuilt the entire hero section of my website in static HTML, and the LCP metric was still running high.
Any help on understanding this metric better, and maybe some tips/tricks would be greatly appreciated.

To be clear, it is only your mobile score that is low, not your desktop. Can you disable your slider in mobile and just use a single static image?

Your real users (top report) are getting a good LCP, and that's what is important.
Maybe the bad lab score comes from the testing tool (which is not a human having to go through human verification.
My browser set to mobile emulation could not get past the verification process, so I could not test.

@ChrisHaas Unfortunately, disabling the slider is out of the question

Can you try disabling the slider to see if that increases the score? If it gets better then at least you know something to optimize.

Try delaying javascript using "Flying Scripts" free plugin.
In settings define rule to delay all plugin related js, analytics, inline jquery scripts.
Write in "Include keywords":
/plugins/
jQuery(
comment
migrate
gtag

And select "timeout" 5 seconds.
After check your website to make sure that no big layout shifts happening.
Using this I always get 90+ score on mobile for all pages on my WordPress website.
